# Extract Topic Scores for Documents LDA Gensim Python

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to extract topic scores for documents in my dataset after using and LDA model. Specifically, I have followed most of the code from here: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/

I have completed the topic model and have the results I want, but the provided code only gives the most dominant topic for each document. Is there a simple way to modify the following code to give me the scores for say the 5 most dominant topics?

```
##dominant topic for each document
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=optimal_model, corpus=corpus, texts=data):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Get main topic in each document
for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
    row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
    # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
    for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
        if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
            wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
            topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
            sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
        else:
            break
sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']

# Add original text to the end of the output
contents = pd.Series(texts)
sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
return(sent_topics_df)


df_topic_sents_keywords = format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=optimal_model, corpus=corpus, texts=data)

# Format
df_dominant_topic = df_topic_sents_keywords.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']

# Show
df_dominant_topic.head(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right this is a crusty example because you haven't provided data to reproduce but using some gensim testing corpus, texts and dictionary we can do:

```py
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, common_corpus, common_dictionary
from gensim.models import LdaModel

# train a quick lda model using the common _corpus, _dictionary and _texts from gensim
optimal_model = LdaModel(common_corpus, id2word=common_dictionary, num_topics=10)
```

We can then rewrite the function slightly to become:

```py
import pandas as pd

##dominant topic for each document
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=optimal_model, 
                            corpus=common_corpus, 
                            texts=common_texts, 
                            n=1):
    """
    A function for extracting a number of dominant topics for a given document
    using an existing LDA model
    """
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()


    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            # we use range here to iterate over the n parameter
            if j in range(n):  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(
                    # and also use the i value here to get the document label
                    pd.Series([int(i), int(topic_num), round(prop_topic, 4), topic_keywords]),
                    ignore_index=True,
                )
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ["Document", "Dominant_Topic", "Perc_Contribution", "Topic_Keywords"]

    # Add original text to the end of the output
    text_col = [texts[int(i)] for i in sent_topics_df.Document.tolist()]
    contents = pd.Series(text_col, name='original_texts')
    sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)
    return sent_topics_df
```

Then we can use the function like this:

```py
format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=optimal_model, corpus=common_corpus, texts=common_texts, n=2)
```

Where the `n` parameter specifies the number of dominant topics you want to extract.

Comment: For some reason, the code has been working since yesterday but now it isn't anymore. This is the error I am getting: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'`. I isolated the problem at this line of your snippet: `row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)`. Any idea?

Comment: It's difficult to debug from what you've said here. But at first i'd check the format of the topic scores of your corpus that you get from `ldamodel[corpus]`. If you transform it into a list with `list(ldamodel[corpus])` it should return a list for each document where each item is a tuple of (topic number, probabilty). I would check your data looks like that and work from there

Comment: I've created a gist so you can see what I mean and how the example still works with the gensim testing data - https://gist.github.com/Sparrow0hawk/bf3bf62abc4a623cf1c5f5cb20d806a6

Comment: @Sparrow0hawk
when I use it with gensim dictionary and corpus I get `list index out of range`

Comment: @AliA.Jalil what version of gensim are you using? and are you using the `from gensim.test.utils import common_texts, common_corpus, common_dictionary` test dictionary and corpus? If you're using your own dictionary and corpus it's difficult to troubleshoot with the information you've provided. Consider providing a link to a reproducible example and I can try and advise.

Comment: Sparrow0hawk thanks for your reply, I use last version of gensim with my own corpus, created by gensim `doc2bow`

Comment: @AliA.Jalil OK, without sharing more information it's not possible to troubleshoot the issue you're having. You should check if the above example with the gensim testing data works and then look at what is different between the test data and your own data.